# Turn on 2 LEDs, then blink one forever on button press

Tags: python, button, raspberry-pi, gpio, led

I need help. I need my Raspberry Pi to turn on a Yellow LED and a Red LED. Then, when the Yellow button is pressed, I need the Yellow LED to start blinking forever, and for the Red LED to remain on.

Here is the code I have but it only partially works. It turns the Red LED on but the Yellow LED is off. (I thought that by setting GPIO.output(17, GPIO.HIGH) that that would turn the Yellow LED on, as it does for the Red LED, but it doesn’t.)

Pressing the Yellow button starts the Yellow LED blinking forever, which is correct behavior but I need both LEDs to be on and then the Yellow to start blinking forever on the button press.

What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setwarnings (False)
GPIO.setup(24, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down = GPIO.PUD_DOWN)  #Yellow button
GPIO.setup(17, GPIO.OUT)    #Yellow LED
GPIO.setup(27, GPIO.OUT)    #Red LED
GPIO.output(17, GPIO.HIGH)  #Turn Yellow LED On
GPIO.output(27, GPIO.HIGH)  #Turn Red LED On


blinking = False
while True:
    if GPIO.input(24):
        blinking = True

    if blinking:
        GPIO.output(17, GPIO.HIGH)
        time.sleep(.2)
        GPIO.output(17, GPIO.LOW)
        time.sleep(.2)

    time.sleep(.1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setwarnings (False)
GPIO.setup(24, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down = GPIO.PUD_DOWN)  #Yellow button
GPIO.setup(17, GPIO.OUT)    #Yellow LED
GPIO.setup(27, GPIO.OUT)    #Red LED
GPIO.output(17, GPIO.HIGH)  #Turn Yellow LED On
GPIO.output(27, GPIO.HIGH)  #Turn Red LED On


blinking = False
while True:
    if GPIO.input( 24 ):
        blinking = True

    while blinking:
        GPIO.output(17, GPIO.HIGH)
        time.sleep(.2)
        GPIO.output(17, GPIO.LOW)
        time.sleep(.2)

        time.sleep(.1)
```

Comment: OK, that works! Thank you so much! Now for the second part of the project, I have another script that I want to merge with this one because it uses the same physical button (Yellow button). I tried just merging the two codes, sans the redundant stuff, but the script doesn't run at reboot so I screwed something up.

Comment: I needed to change Pin 24 to a PullUP to match the code that I’m merging in and the button is already wired up, so I found that I could just add “not” to make it an active LOW, like this “if not GPIO.input(24):”

I did and your changes are still working perfectly.

Comment: This needs to be added:
`code`
    import os

def ShutdownDELAY(channel):
    os.system("sudo shutdown -h +1")

GPIO.add_event_detect(24, GPIO.FALLING, callback = ShutdownDELAY, bouncetime = 2000)`code`

Comment: I'm sorry but I read all the help sections about formatting and I can't figure out how to add code to the comments section without it being all jumbled together!

Comment: Eh, not important, it's working correctly with keeping the 2 scripts separate so that's fine, unless someone just feels like showing me how to merge the 2 scripts. If not, no worries, thanks for the help Stuart!